# Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>() always returns null

Tags: asp.net-core, custom-error-pages

I do use `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");` and in my `ErrorController` `Index` action I am calling

```
var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
var path = feature.OriginalPath;
```

but the feature is always null no matter what. Why is it so? I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same problem, `HttpContext.Features.Get<>()` is returning `null`

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul Probably because you get code <400, CodePages workonly for 4xx and 5xx errors, that's why it is null. You might be getting 302.

Answer (score 0):

When you access "https://localhost:44369/error" directly, it will `null` of `IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature`. Only trigger `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` and return StatusCode values when 404 really happended.

1. add to `Configure()` in `Startup.cs`

   app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
2. add `StatusCode404()` to `ErrorController`

   ```
    [Route("error/404")]
    public IActionResult StatusCode404()
    {
        //redirect to the StatusCode404.cshtml
        var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
        var path = feature.OriginalPath;

        return View();
    }
   ```

> Test of result

When access `https://localhost:44369/abc` which not existed

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've done that, I opened a topic on ASP .NET  Core explaining more. The Middleware never  executes the `ReExecute` part of itself: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24207 thus the `IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature()`; is never added.

Comment: UseStatusCodePages(IApplicationBuilder) adds a StatusCodePages middleware with a default response handler that checks for responses with status codes between 400 and 599 that do not have a body.

Comment: I will follow up your issue on github.