# Why is IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature always null with a status code of 500?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am getting an unhandled exception in my ASP.NET Razor Pages application. My `Error.cshtml` page emails me the details, but doesn't (currently) include the query string. I need this to work out why the exception is happening.

I have the following code in `Startup.cs` to set up error handling (check for `IsDevelopment` removed for testing)...

```cs
    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
      app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error", "?code={0}");
      // etc...
    }
```

The `Error.cshtml.cs` code contains code to get `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature`, which works fine. It also contains this code to get the query string...

```cs
IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature statusCodeReExecuteFeature =
    HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
```

(code taken [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0))

When my code throws an unhandled exception, which generates an HTTP status code of 500, the code above returns null, so I can't get the query string.

According to the second comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037664/request-httpcontext-features-getistatuscodereexecutefeature-always-returns-n), CodePages works only for 4xx and 5xx errors. However, as I'm getting a 500 (which I can see in the browser dev tools), I don't understand why it's null.

Anyone able to explain why it's null, and how I can get the query string? Please let me know if there is anything more I can add to clarify.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037664/request-httpcontext-features-getistatuscodereexecutefeature-always-returns-n)

Comment: @Llama Thanks, but I don't think so. That's the page I linked in my question, where the 2nd comment on the question says that it's supposed to work for code 500. When the exception happens, `Error.cshtml` gets called (although the browser shows the requested URL), but the call to get `IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature` returns null. Thanks anyway, any other ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on my side, I suggest you could refer the [official sample](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/error-handling/samples/5.x/ErrorHandlingSample)(in the Program.cs, change the configuration to use StartupSCreX.cs, then set a break point in the MyStatusCode2.cshtml.cs). In this sample, when throw the 500 error, the `statusCodeReExecuteFeature` is not null, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MRnJ.gif). If still not working, I suggest you could create a simple sample to reproduce the problem and share it via github.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when using both `UseExceptionHandler` and `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` on the same page/controller action you need to try both `IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature` and `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature` to support each use-case.

I use this method:

```cs
private string GetUrl()
{
    // Handles non-exception related Status Codes
    var statusCodeReExecuteFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
    if (statusCodeReExecuteFeature != null) return statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalPath;
    
    // Handles exception related status codes
    var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
    if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature != null) return exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path;

    // Falls back to current url, probably something like /status/{code}
    return Request.GetDisplayUrl();
}
```